# Updating of JLabel not behaving properly inside SwingWorker thread

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, repaint, swingworker

I am trying to update JLabel in some expected behaviour like -

COND 1 : JLabel should display for 5 seconds , then it should be invisible for next 3 seconds then it should be visible for 5 second and so on.

COND 2 : JLabel should display for 0.5 second , then it should be invisible for next 3 secons..

Kind of any permutation combination , the behaviour should work.
Following is the sample code-

```
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Main
{
    static CounterTask task;

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {

        final JLabel label = new JLabel( "TEST ME " );
        JButton startButton = new JButton( "Start" );
        startButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
            {
                task = new CounterTask( label );
                task.execute();
            }
        } );

        JButton cancelButton = new JButton( "Cancel" );
        cancelButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
            {
                task.cancel( true );
            }
        } );

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add( startButton );
        buttonPanel.add( cancelButton );

        JPanel cp = new JPanel();
        LayoutManager layout = new BoxLayout( cp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS );
        cp.setLayout( layout );
        cp.add( buttonPanel );
        cp.add( label );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setContentPane( cp );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}

class CounterTask
    extends SwingWorker< Integer, Integer >
{
    int DELAY = 3000;

    JLabel label;

    int WAIT = 5000;

    public CounterTask ( JLabel label )
    {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground () throws Exception
    {
        int i = 0;
        int count = 1000;
        while ( !isCancelled() && i < count )
        {
            i++;
            publish( new Integer[] { i } );
            label.setVisible( false );
            Thread.sleep( DELAY );
        }
        return count;
    }

    protected void process ( List< Integer > chunks )
    {
        Integer strContent = chunks.get( chunks.size() - 1 );
        label.setVisible( true );
        label.validate();
        label.setText( "DISPLAYING " + strContent );
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep( WAIT );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done ()
    {
        if ( isCancelled() )
            System.out.println( "Cancelled !" );
        else
            System.out.println( "Done !" );
    }
}
```

I am definately doing something wrong , as this combination works for some data and mostly JLabel becomes invisible throughout , but if I put SOP , I get proper data at proper delay and wait time.

The above code of Swing worker has two variable WAIT , DELAY .
WAIT makes the JLabel visible for X seconds and DELAY make the JLAbel invisible for Y seconds. But if try with different perm and comb you will realize JLabel visibility not working as expected. It may be because of EDT updates of Label or something to do with repaint. Not sure the root cause.

Expected :

> 1. Want to make the code work like SOP working or in ideal case.
> 2. Need to know the reason of not behaving properly.

Comment: Sleeping in the EDT isn't going to help you, process is executed within the EDT. Changing the state of the label in the doInBackground is also a violation of the single thread rules of Swing, no, it's behaving exactly as you have coded it. Oh and you have a race condition between the doInBackground and process methods

Comment: Thanks for the input , so it does mean I need to find a way to wait inside EDT , and that can't be a normal Thread. Second regarding race condition , I expected with the flow avoiding any race , can you provide a little hint.

Comment: no, you _never_ wait on the EDT: instead put all the logic into the doInBackground, and publish the label state

Comment: Moreover, it would be wise, that instead of using `setVisible(true/false)`, simply use `setText(""/"newValue")`. So you really doesn't have to `revalidate()/repaint()` each time. And, simply iterate over `chunks` to display the content on the `JLabel` instead of explicitly taking the top value from the list and displaying the same on the `JLabel` i.e. simply put only these two lines in `process()` method `for (Integer chunk : chunks)
label.setText( "DISPLAYING " + chunk.toString() );` :-) +1 for provide a runnable example :-)

Comment: all above comments have been taken into account and problem solved :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwingWorker is an overkill for just a blinking label. Try the following timer-based approach, it requires no thread magic at all:

```
public class Main {
private static Timer setVisibleTimer;
private static Timer setInvisibleTimer;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JLabel label = new JLabel("TEST ME ");
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setVisibleTimer = new Timer(8000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            setInvisibleTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            setVisibleTimer.start();
            setInvisibleTimer.start();
        }
    });

    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setVisible(true);
            if (setVisibleTimer != null){
                setInvisibleTimer.stop();
                setVisibleTimer.stop();
            }
        }
    });

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(startButton);
    buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);

    JPanel cp = new JPanel();
    LayoutManager layout = new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    cp.setLayout(layout);
    cp.add(buttonPanel);
    cp.add(label);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(cp);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Nb you can change the delay of a timer from within the actionPerformed event, it takes a little extra work ;)

Answer (score 4):

> no, you never wait on the EDT: instead put all the logic into the
>   doInBackground, and publish the label state

To flesh out my comment with a bit of code (could be done in a Timer, but actually I like workers :)

```
static class LabelState {
    int count;
    boolean visible;

    public LabelState(boolean visible, int count) {
        this.count = count;
        this.visible = visible;
    }
}
static class CounterTask extends SwingWorker<Void, LabelState> {
    int DELAY = 3000;

    JLabel label;

    int WAIT = 5000;

    public CounterTask(JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        int i = 0;
        int count = 1000;
        while (!isCancelled() && i < count) {
            i++;
            publish(new LabelState(false, i));
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            i++;
            publish(new LabelState(true, i));
            Thread.sleep(WAIT);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void process(List<LabelState> chunks) {
        LabelState strContent = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        label.setVisible(strContent.visible);
        label.validate();
        label.setText("DISPLAYING " + strContent.count);
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        if (isCancelled())
            System.out.println("Cancelled !");
        else
            System.out.println("Done !");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I liked this idea, though why not simply use `setText("")` instead of `hiding and showing JLabel` again and again :-)